# Invalid syntax. What have I gotten wrong?? Python 2.7.13

Tags: python-2.7

```
import os
def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir("/Users/mbh/Desktop/prank")
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print ("Current working directory is ")
    os.chdir("/Users/mbh/Desktop/prank")
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789")
    os.chdir(saved_path)
**rename_files()** <-- Says that this is invalid syntax for some reason.
```

I am trying to write a program that renames a couple of files in a folder. I want the program to delete numbers from the filenames.

Comment: Did you count your parens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789")
```

You forgot the second closing brace in the end of the line. It should look like this

```
os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))
```

Everything else seems to be correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly after adding the brace.